# What happened to Constance Spano?

Tags: independence-day, independence-day-resurgence

In the movie *Independence Day* (1996), there is a romantic subplot featuring David Levinson (played by Jeff Goldblum) and Constance Spano (played by Margaret Colin), leading to one of my favorite bits of dialog from the movie:

> **Julius Levinson:** There was a lot of love there.
>   **David Levinson:** Love was never our problem.

In the movie *Independence Day: Resurgence* (2016), many actors from the first movie returned, and Jeff Goldblum was one of them.  But Margaret Colin did not return.

I'm actually interested in both the in-universe explanation and the real-world explanation.  Do we know either one?

Here's what I have found:

- an [interview](https://collider.com/jeff-goldblum-independence-day-2-interview/) with Jeff Goldblum where he says there is an in-universe explanation but he doesn't say what it was.
- a [Wikia page](https://independenceday.wikia.com/wiki/Constance_Spano) that says the character was killed in a car crash during the events of the novel *Independence Day: Crucible*.  Is that novel canon with the movie?

Comment: A correction on the quote, which is also one of my favorites. It was in Air Force One and it was Julius Levinson and Constance Spano, not David. Julius: There's still love there, I think. Constance: Love was never our problem. Julius: All you need is love. John Lennon...smart man...shot in the back...very sad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### She ded.

According to the novel [Independence Day: Crucible](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28367546-independence-day) she was killed in a car accident.

> Instead he had tap water, and he sat alone on the couch and he felt her absence. The lack of Connie.
>   This time, saving the world wouldn’t be enough to get her back. **He would have to rewind time itself, to the moment before the teenager in the SUV decided to send a text to his girlfriend, before he coasted through a red light at nearly eighty miles an hour. They had tried to comfort him by saying she probably never felt it, never knew what was happening. But he knew Connie would have wanted to see it coming.**
>   Now Nevada had a new Senator, and he had a vacuum in him as big as outer space that he hadn’t even begun to fill.

Since this book is described as being the "*official*" prequel, there's every indication that it can be considered canon to the films.

Comment: As to why she's not in the sequel, I suspect the answer is that she's nearly 60 years old. Having her as the love-interest wouldn't appeal to younger audiences.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably that simple.

Comment: Upvoted for "she ded". Gave me a great laugh.